# Java Exception when opening iReport

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

Here is the error I'm getting. Tried to open other version of ireport and didn't encountered any errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:1313821769
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:188)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:661)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:346)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:76)
    at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

I am using java 7 on my ireport.conf, also I am using Ubuntu

```
jdkhome="/usr/jdk1.7.0_55.for.tmpfs/"
```

The application is working fine this morning and this just happens, 
I've tried search for solutions but the only solutions I found on the internet is to check whether I am using java 7 which I am.
I guess the port has something to do with this but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IReport, but error message says the port number is incorrect - check your settings, especially related to port number

Comment: It looks like the port number was changed to an invalid value somewhere. Max port number is `65535` and your port number is `1313821769`

Comment: @Sergi and migron Thanks, unfortunately I do not know where should I correct the port number. If you have any Idea where please let me know. I only run the app on an executable file and I can't find where the port number is.

Comment: Please check your startup script and conf file - it looks like you pass port number as argument to your program

Comment: @Sergi Thank you for the advise, this was fixed by the accepted answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the *lock* file.

Try to find it using this command:

```
find /home/your_user_name -name lock
```

It will be located in path like */home/your_user_name/.ireport/4.5.1/lock*

Delete this file and try to start iReport again.